# Why Setting Qt::SplashScreen flag prevent closing

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qwindow

I have `QMainWindow` which embed a `QQuickWidget`.
The `QQuickWidget` display two differents qml (`splash.qml` and `main.qml`) according to the state of the app (initialized or not).

I want my window to be in *splashScreen* mode when the `splash.qml` is displayed, so I did :

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QMainWindow * parent) :QMainWindow(parent)
{
    QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_DontCreateNativeWidgetSiblings);

    mDefaultFlags = windowFlags();
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose, true);
    setWindowFlags(Qt::SplashScreen);

    mQuickWidget = new QQuickWidget(this);
    //...
    setCentralWidget(mQuickWidget);

    mQuickWidget->show();
}
```

The QML trigger a slot when the init is done and the other qml file is loaded. I then reset the flags to their default value to go back from splashscreen :

```
void MainWindow::UpdateWindowAfterInit()
{
    setWindowFlags(mDefaultFlags);
    show();
}
```

Everything goes as expected , but when I try to close my app it never reach the end of the `main()` whereas it close nicely if i don't apply the `Qt::SplashScreen` flag.

What should I do to be able to close my app ?

Comment: Try using `Qt::FramelessWindowHint` instead of the `Qt::SplashScreen` flag. This might be a bug in QT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, let's try to understand why it doesn't work as you expect.

By looking at the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#close) of `QWidget::close`, we have the following (emphasis mine):

> The `QApplication::lastWindowClosed()` signal is emitted when the last visible primary window (i.e. window with no parent) **with the `Qt::WA_QuitOnClose`** attribute set is closed. **By default this attribute is set for all widgets except transient windows such as splash screens**, tool windows, and popup menus.

On the other side, we have this for `Qt::WA_QuitOnClose`:

> Makes Qt quit the application when the last widget with the attribute set has accepted `closeEvent()`. This behavior can be modified with the `QApplication::quitOnLastWindowClosed` property. By default this attribute is set for all widgets of type `Qt::Window`.

Therefore the suspect is that attributes you set or you think are set are actually reset when you change the flags.

By looking at the code, we have the following:

- [Here](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/kernel/qwidget.cpp#n10377) is the actual implementation of `setWindowFlags`. You can see that the function `adjustQuitOnCloseAttribute` is invoked if *the old type was a window* (that is, if you had the `Qt::Window` flag set and that's your case).
- [Here](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/kernel/qwidget.cpp#n12181) is the actual implementation of `adjustQuitOnCloseAttribute` and this happens:

  ```
  // ...

  if (type != Qt::Widget && type != Qt::Window && type != Qt::Dialog)
      q->setAttribute(Qt::WA_QuitOnClose, false);

  // ...
  ```

  This means that attribute `Qt::WA_QuitOnClose` is set to `false` when you set the flag `Qt::SplashScreen`.

Finally, we have the following for `Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose`:

> Makes Qt delete this widget when the widget has accepted the close event (see `QWidget::closeEvent()`).

For you don't have anymore the `Qt::WA_QuitOnClose` set, the window no longer accepts the `close` event and it is not destroyed.

More important, it is not closed, that is what you are observing in your application. This is not a bug of Qt, it is a (quite badly) documented intended behavior.

---

Now, we can try to figure what to do to solve the problem.

Probably, it's suffice to set the right flags and attributes in the right order to work around it.
I'm not sure about that, but you can give it a try:

```
setWindowFlags(Qt::SplashScreen);
setAttribute(Qt::WA_QuitOnClose, true);
setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose, true);
```

Comment: Indeed , re setting the attribute Qt::WA_QuitOnClose to true solve the problem. Thanks

Comment: @grunk I'm glad to know that it works. I tried to give you also in insight of the reasons, to better understand why it didn't work as you expected. Hoping it helped. ;-)

Comment: Btw response from the qt support  : "This is the cause of the problem and it is actually a bug in Qt since it
should have handled this already. You can track this patch online here":

https://codereview.qt-project.org/176665

Comment: @grunk I guess it's worth linking this Q/A to the issue. It would help tracking down what's happening under the hood at least.

Comment: @grunk Note also the text of the issue: _If the window flags change from a type that would have turned off the
WA_QuitOnClose attribute then it should be set back to be on when
changing back to a type that allows it_. You are not _changing back anything. This is not what you observed or, at least, described in the question.

Comment: I'm changing back when i revert to mDefaultFlags. My window have "standards" flags , i switch to splashscreen then come back to original flags.